# Link two cells of a column in different sheets if a value in a cell of other column matches in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, lookup-tables

I have a workbook with 7 sheets containing part number of a product in column and its cost in adjacent column. And the 7th sheet contains total number of parts in all the sheets. I want to change cost of some products but then I have to do the same in all sheets. Is there a way by which it automatically finds and changes cost in individual sheets when i change it in the sheet containing total?

Comment: Post some example data

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia I dont have enough reputation to post image. But you can make a column let's say A with different part numbers and Column B with quantity and C with Cost. Now there are 6 sheets with lot of part numbers. From which some are same. so in total sheet quantity of same part numbers is added. Now I need cost in all sheets of same part number to change when i change cost of a part number in total sheet.

Comment: Just post data, thats fine. No need image

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia The edited comment will help you out. Just take any mixture of numbers and alphabets as part number. Just to let you know all sheets have part numbers some of which are same and some are different so the row of the part number will be different in all sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP on the first 6 sheets to match the price to each part number.

So, in each "cost" column on the first 6 sheets, enter this formula (assuming Cost on Sheet7 is still in column C):

```
=IFERROR(IF($A1="","",VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet7!$A:$C,3,FALSE)),"")
```

If you have header row(s) then just replace the two instances of $A1 in the formula with whatever the first row of data is (e.g. $A2), paste the formula into that row in column C on Sheet1, then drag-copy the formula down as far as you want. Repeat for sheets 2-6.

Comment: In my excel sheet the formula became
 `=IFERROR(IF($F7="","",VLOOKUP($F7,Total!$F:$I,3,FALSE)),"")`
 But now the cell goes blank. It doesnt Show any value.

Comment: Well if F is your product number column in the "Total" sheet, and I is the cost column on the "Total" sheet, then the number before FALSE needs to be 4, not 3, since I is the fourth column in the range $F:$I.